# Any alternatives for a responsive process flow diagram suitable for mobile

Tags: charts, design-process

Hi I am looking for alternatives for this process diagram. You should be able to click on each of the sections (interactive), which results in the box opening up with further explanation

I will be using this on the website. Initial thought was to use the circle process ( image below) but found that its not suitable for mobile. Please advise 
[image]

Comment: Impossible to advise you until we understand what you are trying to achieve for your users and what the goal of the application is.

Comment: I am looking for an alternative option to explain an investment process ( end to end) to the user. As it is very text heavy, information about each step will be displayed only on selection.  I cant seem to figure out an alternative version to represent apart from timelines.

Comment: That doesn't explain your use case, i.e. the who, why and how.

Answer (score 1):

I propose animation + interactivity

- Click on the central step to see the info modal window
- Click on the info modal to close it
- Click on the top or bottom step to go to the next or previous

For a better interpretation, each step should have the corresponding order number somewhere on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two objectives for the UI:

1. Firstly, communicate how the information is connected in the 'flow diagram'
2. Allow the user to read more information on each step

The above solution from Danielillo works well, though I am not a fan of having to open/close overlays before navigating to each new piece of content.

I think the key is providing context for the user.

Solution: Have two states - overview and detail, and allow the user to navigate through content at each state.

- First state: User can navigate around different steps of the 'flow diagram'
- Second state: (Upon clicking a step), the user can then read the detail, and continue navigating steps at this detail level